# React.js: Using ! operator in render results in immediate reversal

Tags: reactjs

At first I thought my checkbox was broken or not bound to state but then I saw it was indeed switching boolean values, albiet extremely fast:

```
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 false "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 true "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 false "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 true "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 false "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 true "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 false "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 true "=====addCouponBorder====="
index.jsx_+_160_modules:18501 false "=====addCouponBorder====="
```

I think I'm creating a race condition between the state value and component rerender as the onClick handler is inside of return, which I believe is the same as render() for functional components.

What is a better way to write this to allow the checkbox to switch values without interference?

The below custom components come from the Material UI react library.

```
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<Checkbox
        checked={addCouponBorder} // this is a boolean value
        onClick={() => setAddCouponBorder(!addCouponBorder)}
      />}
      label={'Label text.'}
      className={styles.formChild}
    />
```

**Update**

As requested here is the full component code

```js
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";


import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem"
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import SnackBar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import SnackBarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent';
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

import AjaxRequestor from "./utilities/AjaxRequestor";

// todo create a success / error Snackbar and send it data (will be a direct child)

const ajaxRequestor = new AjaxRequestor();


const AddCouponForm = props => {
  let {clientNonce, apiBaseUrl} = props;
  const styles = jssStyles();

  ////// State for inputs //////
  const [pageTarget, setPageTarget] = useState('');
  const [displayThreshold, setDisplayThreshold] = useState(0);
  const [numberOfOffers, setNumberOfOffers] = useState(0);
  const [couponHeadline, setCouponHeadline] = useState('');
  const [couponDescription, setCouponDescription] = useState('');

  ////// State for dropdowns //////
  const [headlineTextColor, setHeadlineTextColor] = useState("");
  const [headlineBackgroundColor, setHeadlineBackgroundColor] = useState("");
  const [descriptionTextColor, setDescriptionTextColor] = useState("");
  const [descriptionBackgroundColor, setDescriptionBackgroundColor] = useState("");

  ////// Checkbox State //////
  const [addCouponBorder, setAddCouponBorder] = useState(true);


  /** Resets all the form state variables
   * @return void
   */
  const resetAddCouponState = () => {
    setPageTarget("");
    setDisplayThreshold(0);
    setNumberOfOffers(0);
    setCouponHeadline("");
    setCouponDescription("");
    setHeadlineTextColor("");
    setHeadlineBackgroundColor("");
    setDescriptionTextColor("");
    setDescriptionBackgroundColor("");
    setAddCouponBorder(true);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(addCouponBorder, `=====addCouponBorder=====`);
  }, [addCouponBorder]);



  /** Form Handling
   * Submits post request
   * @return: object. If success, success key. if error, error key.
   */
  const postCouponAndSetSnackBarMessage = async () => {
    // push all state keys into an object
    const formData = {
      pageTarget, // target table
      displayThreshold, // target table
      numberOfOffers, // target table
      couponHeadline, // coupon table
      couponDescription, // coupon table
      headlineTextColor, // coupon table
      headlineBackgroundColor, // coupon table
      descriptionTextColor, // coupon table
      descriptionBackgroundColor, // coupon table
      addCouponBorder,
      clientNonce
    };

    console.log(formData, `=====formData=====`);

    const response = await ajaxRequestor.post( `${apiBaseUrl}/${namepaceAndVersion}/add`, formData);
    setupSnackBarData(response);
    resetAddCouponState();
  };



  /** Snackbar
   * Will immediately be handed success or error information to fire
   *
   * State will not be held. This would cause problems with future additions
   */
  const snackBarTypes = Object.freeze({
    success : 'success',
    error : 'error'
  });

  const [snackBarType, setSnackBarType] = useState('');
  const [snackBarMessage, setSnackBarMessage] = useState('');

  /** Sets the snackbar state
   * A component prop automatically blanks it out after a preset time (in another component prop)
   */
  const setupSnackBarData = responseData => {
    if (responseData.newCouponId) {
      // fire snackbar with success state
      setSnackBarType(snackBarTypes.success);
      setSnackBarMessage(`Successfully added a new coupon. ID: ${ responseData.newCouponId }. Click 'View Coupons' to see your new coupon.`);
    } else if (responseData.error) {
      // setup error snackBar
      setSnackBarType(snackBarTypes.error);
      setSnackBarMessage(responseData.error);
    }
  };


  const generateColorOptions = () => {
    const colors = ['black', 'blue', 'brown', 'gray', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 'red', 'yellow', 'white'];

    const menuJsx = colors.map(color => (
      <MenuItem
        value={color}
        key={color}
      >
        {color}
      </MenuItem>
    ));

    return menuJsx;
  };


  return (
    <div
    >
      <Typography
        className={[styles.all, styles.paragraphSpacing].join(" ")}
        variant={'h6'}
      >Add Coupons Form</Typography>

      <Typography
        className={[styles.all, styles.paragraphSpacing].join(" ")}
        variant={'subtitle2'}
      >There are 2 main parts to add a coupon. First are the coupon settings itself, including information like the text and colors. Then you will also need to define the page that a user must visit, and how many times to count visits before showing a coupon</Typography>
      <Typography
        className={[styles.all, styles.paragraphSpacing].join(" ")}
        variant={'subtitle2'}
      >Click here for a full explanation of how the plugin works and how to setup your first coupon</Typography>


      <form
        className={[styles.form, styles.all].join(" ")}
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          postCouponAndSetSnackBarMessage();
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          label="Target page"
          helperText='Copy and paste the target page for the coupon to be shown here'
          name='targetPage'
          className={styles.formChild}
          value={pageTarget}
          onChange={e => setPageTarget(e.target.value)}

        />
        <TextField
          label='Delay before showing offer'
          helperText="How many times a user should visit this page before the coupon is offered?"
          required
          name='displayThreshold'
          type='number'
          value={displayThreshold}
          onChange={e => setDisplayThreshold(e.target.value)}
          className={styles.formChild}
        />
        <TextField
          label='Number of times offer shown'
          helperText="Maximum number of visits the user then sees the coupon"
          required
          name='numberOfOffers'
          type='number'
          value={numberOfOffers}
          onChange={e => setNumberOfOffers(e.target.value)}
          className={styles.formChild}
        />
        <TextField
          label='Coupon Headline'
          multiline
          placeholder='On the fence? Special Offer Just For You!'
          name='couponHeadline'
          className={styles.formChild}
          value={couponHeadline}
          onChange={e => setCouponHeadline(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          label='Coupon Description'
          multiline
          placeholder="Buy now and take 10% off! Use coupon code 'OffTheFence' at checkout"
          className={styles.formChild}
          value={couponDescription}
          onChange={e => setCouponDescription(e.target.value)}
        />

        <div
          id="flexChildContainer"
          className={styles.formChild}
        >
          <InputLabel htmlFor='headlineTextColor'>
            Headline Text Color
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            id='headlineTextColor'
            className={styles.dropDownSelect}
            value={headlineTextColor}
            onChange={e => {
              setHeadlineTextColor(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            {generateColorOptions()}
          </Select>
        </div>

        <div id="flexChildContainer"
             className={styles.formChild}
             defaultValue={headlineBackgroundColor}

        >
          <InputLabel htmlFor='headlineBackgroundColor'>
            Headline Background Color
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            id='headlineBackgroundColor'
            className={styles.dropDownSelect}
            value={headlineBackgroundColor}
            onChange={e => setHeadlineBackgroundColor(e.target.value)}
          >
            {generateColorOptions()}
          </Select>
        </div>

        <div id="flexChildContainer"
             className={styles.formChild}
        >
          <InputLabel htmlFor='descriptionTextColor'>
            Description Text Color
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            id='descriptionTextColor'
            className={styles.dropDownSelect}
            value={descriptionTextColor}
            onChange={e => setDescriptionTextColor(e.target.value)}
          >
            {generateColorOptions()}
          </Select>
        </div>

        <div id="flexChildContainer"
             className={styles.formChild}
        >
          <InputLabel htmlFor='descriptionBackgroundColor'>
            Description Background Color
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            id='descriptionBackgroundColor'
            className={styles.dropDownSelect}
            value={descriptionBackgroundColor}
            onChange={e => setDescriptionBackgroundColor(e.target.value)}
          >
            {generateColorOptions()}
          </Select>
        </div>

        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox
            checked={addCouponBorder}
            onClick={() => setAddCouponBorder(!addCouponBorder)}
          />}
          label={'Include a dashed border around this coupon. The dashes will be the same color as the description text.'}
          className={styles.formChild}
        />


        <Button
          type='submit'
          className={styles.addButton}
        >Add Coupon</Button>
      </form>

      {/*
       The snackbar below is triggered by an ajax response
       It is closed automatically, triggering onClose
       onClose wipes state keys for the next round (add or submit attempt).
       */}

      <SnackBar
        open={Boolean(snackBarType)}
        autoHideDuration={10000}
        message={<p>{snackBarMessage}</p>}
        onClose={() =>  {
          setSnackBarType('');
          setSnackBarMessage('');
        }}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center'
        }}
      />

    </div>
  );
};



////// Styles //////

const jssStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  all : {
    maxWidth : '500px',
    padding: '0 3vw'
  },
  form: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 0, 0),
    display : "flex",
    flexFlow : "column wrap",
    justifyContent : 'space-around',
  },
  addButton: {
    margin: theme.spacing(5, 2, 20, 2)
    , padding: theme.spacing(1, 2, 1, 2)
    , border : '2px dashed brown'
  },
  dropDownSelect : {
    minWidth : '300px'
  },
  formChild : {
    margin : '40px 0 0 0',
  },
  errorSnackbar : {
    backgroundColor : theme.palette.error.dark
  },
  paragraphSpacing : {
    padding : theme.spacing(2, 2, 0, 2),
  }
}));

export default AddCouponForm;
```

Comment: Can you paste your full component here? I'd like to see where you're defining `setAddCouponBorder`.

Comment: there should be no race conditions because state change causes rerender, not just happens in same time. try extend your sample so it would be possible to reproduce

Comment: @JMadelaine Ok, the full component code is posted in the top post now

Comment: Whenever you compute the state based on the previous state value, you should pass a function that gets passed the latest state value: `setAddCouponBorder(v => !v)`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: @FelixKling didn't fix it (onChange was needed instead) but I will remember this guideline, thanks

Comment: @FelixKling Where in the docs does it state that you should always pass the current state in the function? In the React docs for Hooks, it clearly shows setting state using a parameterless function: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state

Comment: @JMadelaine: See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @FelixKling Yes you're right. When setting state using the current state value we should pass previous state in a function to the set state function. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onChange` instead of `onClick`:

```
<Checkbox
    checked={addCouponBorder}
    onChange={() => setAddCouponBorder(prevAddCouponBorder => !prevAddCouponBorder)}
/>
```

See the [Checkbox API](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/) and [examples](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/).